# iOS Swift: How can we create pin in Pinterest?

Tags: ios, swift, sharing, pinterest

I have all the boards of logged in user and using Pinterest api I am able to fetch the pins from given board but Create pins is not working.

I have create Application on Pinterest Developer https://developers.pinterest.com/

As per document , I have added collaborator for authenticated users. Send perfect parameters for create pins after permission api.

I got perfect response in permission api and in boards but getting error in create pin from my application.

Please look below my code:

```
PDKClient.sharedInstance().createPin(withImageURL: URL.init(string: aImageUrl), link: URL.init(string: "https://www.pinterest.com"), onBoard: myBoardID, description: "Hello All", withSuccess: { (response) in
      //print(response)
        print("Pinterest sucess")
    }, andFailure: { (error) in
       print(error as Any)
         print("Pinterest Fail")
     })
```

For this api **I am always getting 404 or 400 error.**

Please help me for that.

Thanks in advance.